# Shutil Copy File claims file not found despite clearly identifying the file in the print window

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have the following code (file path details kept anonymous):

```
def stu_activities():
    downloadsList = os.listdir("***/Downloads")
    destination = "."
    for file_name in downloadsList:
        if file_name.startswith("Stu_"):
            shutil.copyfile(file_name,destination)

stu_activities()
```

When I run it, it gives me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Stu_activity.pptx'
```

How is it that it claims the file is not found yet it still found it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your real code does not contain "***/Downloads" but a real path.

os.listdir() returns the filename, but not the full path to the filename.

shutil.copyfile() on the other hand needs the full path of the file.
Further the destination of shutil.copyfile() must be a file name and not a directory

```
def stu_activities():
    dir_to_List = "/your/path/Downloads"
    downloadsList = os.listdir(dir_to_list)
    destination = "."
    for file_name in downloadsList:
        if file_name.startswith("Stu_"):
            shutil.copyfile(
                os.path.join(dir_to_list, file_name) ,
                os.path.join(destination, file_name))

stu_activities()
```

Comment: Yes, it does contain a real path, just left out of this post for anonymity. And it worked so thank you. I see what you did.